# How to iterate through changing collection

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code.

```
private void LoopThroughDependsIssues(JIRAOperations jiraOps, string jiraURL, string token, string username, string password, string projectKey, string exportTargetPath, string branch, SVNOperations svnOps, string svnExePath, string changesetDBFile, DependencyManager mgr)
        {
            var tempVar = mgr.Dependencies;
            foreach (var item in tempVar)
            {
                if (item.depends.Length > 0)
                {
                    var templist = item.depends;
                  var  listissues1 = templist.Split(',');
                     for (var i = 0; i < listissues1.Length-1; i++)
                     {
                         var newissue1 = new string[] { listissues1[i].ToString() };
                         newissue1.getChangeSet(jiraOps, jiraURL, token, username, password, projectKey, exportTargetPath, branch, svnOps, svnExePath, changesetDBFile, mgr);
                     }
                    //throw new Exception("Dependencies found");
                }
            }
        }
```

In this, i am iterating through the `mgr.Dependencis` collection. This value is changing in `newissue1.getChangeSet(jiraOps, jiraURL, token, username, password, projectKey, exportTargetPath, branch, svnOps, svnExePath, changesetDBFile, mgr);`
So for every calling of this method, my collection value is increasing. But for first time it is working fine. But while iterating for second time it is giving exception as

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

I think this exception is coming for changing the collection. How to handle this situation.?

My class definition as follows.

```
public class Dependency
     {
         public string issueID { get; set; }
         public string jirastatus { get; set; }
         public int dependencyFound { get; set; }
         public string depends { get; set; }
         public string linked_issues { get; set; }
       }

      public class DependencyManager
      {
          public List<Dependency> Dependencies { get; private set; }
          public DependencyManager()
          {
              this.Dependencies = new List<Dependency>();

          }
}
```

Comment: You could wrap the iterator in an object that could check for and detect changes to the underlying collection.  But that's more trouble than it's worth. You're better of not even bothering with that and simply don't modify the collection when iterating.

Comment: @Jeff..But need to append new values here. For added new values it should run loop once again.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do too much in one pass. Consider breaking this into two functions - one that extracts dependencies to a simple string list of IDs, and another function that loads a list of items given a list of IDs.

Comment: What is getChangeSet? Is it an extension method on string[]? More importantly what it is doing to the DependencyManager?

Comment: getChangeset is extension method. Depenedency manager takes values in the form of list based on the Dependency class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you index into the `Dependencies` collection there wouldn't be an Enumerator created and you can loop through as the collection is modified. This approach could easily cause headaches if the new items are not appended to the end of the list or items are removed.

```
for(int i = 0; i < mgr.Dependencies.Count; i++)
{
  var item = mgr.Dependecies[i];
  if (item.depends.Length > 0)
  {
      // code unchanged
  }
}
```

A safe approach would be to use a `Queue` and populate it with the initial items from `mgr.Dependencies` and then `Enqueue` any additional items you want to process.

```
var toBeProcessed = new Queue<Dependency>(mgr.Dependencies);
while(toBeProcessed.Count > 0)
{
  var item = toBeProcessed.Dequeue();

  // loop

  // if a new dependency gets added that needs processing, just add it to the queue.
  toBeProcessed.Enqueue(newissue1);

}
```

Comment: @Mike.. thanks mike. But it is confusing when i tried with my code. Can you apply this on my code please..!

Comment: @YSSS I have clarified the first example. Actually, the second example is not workable unless you have access to the new Dependency objects that you want to process. I did not read closely enough and thought `newissue1` was of type `Dependency`.

Comment: no.. newissue1 is not just a string[] type. we calling some extension method by using newissues1. thats it.

Comment: @Mike.. Why you used Dequeue() method?

Comment: @YSSS I use `Dequeue()` to get the next item to be processed. It removes an item from the queue (a `Dependency` object). That example shows the another general way to handle your problem which is to copy the collection you are processing. A queue was simply a convenient way to keep track of items to be processed and add items as needed.

Comment: @mikez, Thank you SO much for this suggestion!  I can't believe I'd never used it before, and it's perfect for the async stuff I'm working on.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is just to use the collection as it is at the beginning, without caring about the changes, you can just take an snapshot of the collection:

```
var tempVar = mgr.Dependencies.ToList(); //This will create a new list with the same items
foreach (var item in tempVar) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can iterate if you do not use foreach but a regular loop. If you only add rows to the modified collection at the end this will work with minimal changes.

```
        var tempVar = mgr.Dependencies;
        var cnt = tempvar.Count(); // Only iterate items available when we start

        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        {
           var item = tempVar[i];
```

Comment: What if the collection is modified by removing items o inserting in the middle? This is not a good solution

Comment: Ofcourse it is not a good solution if you remove or insert into the middle. It is if you only add rows at the end. In which case it works perfect. So depending on what your code does this might be a solution that works with very little impact or change. I will add the answer to reflect this better.

Comment: But you say "Only iterate items available when we start" and that's not true